# Run Time Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument - While Saving Word Document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I've been trying to solve this error for a while, and nothing I've found online has seemed to help. Basically I'm running a script in excel VBA that opens a word document, and then opens the Save As dialog box so that I can save the file with the name / location of my choosing. It's at this point that I get the run time error 5.

I'm using the the Do Loop to try to get around the error, and it worked for a while. But for some reason the problem is back now and I have no idea why.

I've added a Do Loop that keeps the code from moving forward until the file has a name. This worked for a while but mysteriously stopped working after a few hours

```
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'Word isn't already running
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

On Error GoTo 0
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(OFile)

'Clear the variable that contains the file path/name
SveReportName = ""


'Save word document as a new file
Set SveReport = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
With SveReport
' 3 is for 97-2003 - include for 2010, remove for 2003
    .FilterIndex = 3
    .Show
    SveReportName = SveReport.SelectedItems.Item(1)
    'This Do statement is here so that VBA just keeps adding 1+1 until the user has had time to name the tech report file, it should stop Run Time Error 5 from appearing
    Do
        a = 1 + 1
    Loop Until IsNull(SveReportName) = False
    wdDoc.SaveAs SveReportName
End With
```

Any idea what else might be going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know what you're expecting `Do a = 1 + 1` to accomplish, but it's not doing whatever that might be. You're also not checking to see if the user cancelled the dialog before you're accessing `SelectedItems`

Comment: @KenWhite The 1+1 itself isn't meant to do anything, it's just some code to run until IsNull(SveReportName) = False. The idea is that this prevents the next line from running until I've named the file.

Comment: No, that's not what it does. `.Show` on the dialog prevents the code from proceeding until the user either selects a file or cancels the dialog. Nothing moves forward before you can name the file with `SeReportName =` and call `wdDoc.SaveAs`. You're just spinning wheels for absolutely no reason (or doing nothing if the user selects a filename). When you step through the code in the debugger, which line specifically is causing the error?

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for the note, I was not aware of that. When I run through the code line by line, I never get the error, everything goes through smoothly. The error only occurs when I run this batch of code all together, after the Save As Dialog box appears, and before I am able to name and save the file. This is why I'm assuming the code was trying to move on before I had completed naming the file.

Comment: @KenWhite I tried it one more time, by putting a stop command before each line and was able to figure out the error was happening at   SveReportName = SveReport.SelectedItems.Item(1). I modified the code and was able to fix it. Thank you for your help! Here is the revised code: '''Set SveReport = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
With SveReport
    .FilterIndex = 3
    If .Show = -1 Then .Execute
End With

SveReportName = wdDoc.Path & "\" & wdDoc.Name
Sheets("Start").Range("C13").Value = SveReportName'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read of the MS docs on the object you're using, and specifically its note about the execute method which should be used right after the show method for a Save As:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog.show

I think it reduces your 'save' code to something like this, though I haven't tried it:

```
'Save word document as a new file
Set SveReport = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
With SveReport
    .FilterIndex = 3
    if .Show = -1 then .Execute
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to figure it out with your and Ken White's help. The code you provided worked, the line that was causing the error was the "SveReportName = SveReport.SelectedItems.Item(1)". I reviewed the code to show: _____________________________ Set SveReport = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
________With SveReport
________    .FilterIndex = 3
________    If .Show = -1 Then .Execute
________End With

________SveReportName = wdDoc.Path & "\" & wdDoc.Name
________Sheets("Start").Range("C13").Value = SveReportName"